# Python for absolute beginners chapter 5 challenge #1: Got Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Chapter 5, of e-book called **"Python Programming for Absolute Beginners"**
has challenge **"Create a program that prints a list of words in random order.
The program should print all the words and not repeat any."**

And for this challenge I had done this[code in right and output in left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA9IV.png)
I don't know what these error are and how to fix them. So how can help myself to fix these problems.

**Code:-**

```
import random
WORDS = ["OVERUSED", "CLAM", "GUAM", "TAFFETA", "PYTHON"]
x = len(WORDS) + 1
count = 0
if count == x:
    exit(0)
while count < int(x):

    word = random.choice(WORDS)
    WORDS.remove(word)  
    print(word)
    count += 1

**Output:-**
root@kali:~/Desktop/Projects# python3 randomWords.py
PYTHON
OVERUSED
TAFFETA
GUAM
CLAM
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 253, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 230, in _randbelow
    r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "randomWords.py", line 9, in <module>
    word = random.choice(WORDS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 255, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

Comment: From glancing at it, it looks like you want `x = len(WORDS)` not `+ 1`

Comment: @pushkin: I believe it should be `x = len(WORDS)`.  He uses `<` not `<=`.

Comment: No bro I want actual numbers of WORDS so I did +1

Comment: @zondo Yep, you're right. fixed

Comment: @SaWin `len(WORDS)` gives you the actual number of words.

Comment: Problem is solved. Thanks you all guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `x` as `len(WORDS) + 1`, but your count starts out at 0.  Because of that, you are trying to get 1 too many random words.  Try `x = len(WORDS)` instead.  Also, you can just say `while count < x:`.  `x` is already an integer.

Comment: Great.  Would you mind marking my answer as the correct one?

Comment: Sorry i am new here too. I would love to but How can i do?

Comment: There should be a grayed-out check mark below the vote count on my answer.  If you click it, it should turn green.

Comment: stack is saying "You can't accept an answer in 1 minute."

Comment: That is probably because it hasn't been 15 minutes yet.